# DXA 2.0 CTP 2 - cm import - ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: dxa, core-service, web8.5, importexportservice, dxa-2.0

I am trying out a DXA 2.0 CTP2 install on Web 8.5 and getting the following error, can anyone offer some direction for what is misconfigured to cause this?
It might not have something to do with DXA exactly, but it is blocking the install.

```
PS C:\software\SDL.DXA.NET.2.0.CTP.2\cms> .\cms-import.ps1
```

> cmdlet cms-import.ps1 at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters:
>   (Type !? for Help.)
>   cmsUrl: http://localhost
>   Copied 'C:\software\SDL.DXA.NET.2.0.CTP.2\cms\DXA Application Data Definition.xml' to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\co
>   nfig\ImportExport\ApplicationData'
>   Get-CoreServiceClient : Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "The message with Action
>   'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/201603/ICoreService/GetCurrentUser' cannot be processed at the
>   receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract
>   mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the
>   receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security
>   requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None)."
>   At C:\software\SDL.DXA.NET.2.0.CTP.2\cms\cms-import.ps1:194 char:22
>   + $coreServiceClient = Get-CoreServiceClient "Service"
>   +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-CoreServiceClient], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActionNotSupportedException,Get-CoreServiceClient

Comment: I wonder if the settings used to connect to the Core Service through PowerShell match that of the Web 8.5 endpoint. It's failing trying to get the Core Service client so I suspect the settings specified in `Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings` might be misconfigured.